# Excel, importing data from different file

Tags: excel, import, automation, autofill

I want to rotate values from a separate Excel file like this:

[image: Source sheet]

To a vertical list:

[image: Desired output]

I mean, after every ninth value, I want the program to start a new column (as in the picture).

I manage to do this manually (ofc B) ) when the different "sheets" are on the same document (Sheet1, Sheet2 etc).

Is this even possible what I am trying, without too much further programming? Should I be using Excel macros? I appreciate all the help I get..!

Comment: Do you want a single column as shown or four columns of nine rows each?

Comment: I want as many rows of nine cells as I can get from this column, where all the values are one below the other. I would also want to find a way to do it automaticly between two separate Excel-files. I want to autofill and Excel-sheet with another one, in a certain way (as I've described, in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Store the data matrix in an array and slice off transposed 'rows' of values.

```
Dim x As Long, vVALs As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    vVALs = .Range("A2:I5").Value2

    For x = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
        .Cells(7, 1).Offset((x - 1) * UBound(vVALs, 2)).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 2), 1) = _
            Application.Transpose(Application.Index(vVALs, x, 0))
    Next x
End With
```

[image]